# Installing phpize on OpenSUSE 12.1

Tags: php, opensuse

I am trying to install phpize on OpenSUSE 12.1.  I have tried the following with the ensuing results.

```
$ sudo zypper install phpize
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'phpize' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'phpize' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

$ sudo zypper install php5-dev
Your password:
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Package 'php5-dev' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.


$ sudo zypper install phpcli-5.3.2-1rt.i686.rpm
Your password:
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides /usr/src/rpm/BUILD/dev/phpcli-5.3.2/sapi/cli/php needed by     phpcli-5.3.2-1rt.i686
 Solution 1: do not install phpcli-5.3.2-1rt.i686
 Solution 2: break phpcli-5.3.2-1rt.i686 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): c
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,
Peter.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo zypper install php5-devel
```